# Gradle project sync failed - Gradle DSL method not found: android()

Tags: android, gradle, build-dependencies

i imported a project that uses roboelectric but it seems that build.gradle file is wrong and i do not know how to fix it. I've checked i have gradle 2.2.1 but i've not figured out the problem yet... My log:

```
Executing tasks: [:]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/dev1/Desktop/DESARROLLO/AndroidTestExample-master/Starter/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Starter'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_43aogzm0wm94eieabvjhdztqe$_run_closure1@eed01a1] on root project 'Starter'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.153 secs
```

And the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/res')
        }
}

configurations {
unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
 }

dependencies {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
}
task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn unitTest

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try to set your `buildToolsVersion` to `21.1.1` instead of 19.0.0 it is probably the cause of your proplem.

try to update android studio too, if it is not.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but it stills saying: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_43aogzm0wm94eieabvjhdztqe$_run_closure1@19a6fd40] on root project 'Starter'.